# Hibernate OneToMany mapping is failing

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

i got the following code:

Car.java:

```
    package org.tjatte;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Car_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int carId;

    @Column(name = "Car_DESIGNATION", nullable = false)
    private String designation;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GARAGE_ID")
    public Garage carGarage;


    public Car(String bez) {
        this.designation = bez;
    }

    public int getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public void setCarId(int carId) {
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public Garage getCarGarage() {
        return carGarage;
    }

    public void setCarGarage(Garage carGarage) {
        this.carGarage = carGarage;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Designation: " + getDesignation());
    }
}
```

Garage.java

```
    package org.tjatte;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Garage")
public class Garage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Garage_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int garageId;

    @Column(name = "Garage_DESIGNATION", nullable = false)
    private String designation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carGarage", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "GARAGE_ID")
    public List<Car> carsInGarage = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public Garage(String bez) {
        this.designation = bez;
    }

    public int getGarageId() {
        return garageId;
    }

    public void setGarageId(int garageId) {
        this.garageId = garageId;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public List<Car> getCarsInGarage() {
        return carsInGarage;
    }

    public void setCarsInGarage(List<Car> carsInGarage) {
        this.carsInGarage = carsInGarage;
    }

    public void print() {
        for(Car c : carsInGarage) {
            c.print();
        }
    }

}
```

MainTest.java

```
    package org.tjatte;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Garage garage = new Garage("Big");
        Car oneCar = new Car("Opel");
        Car anotherCar = new Car("Mercedes");
        garage.setCarsInGarage(Arrays.asList(oneCar, anotherCar));
        session.save(garage);
        tx.commit();

    }

}
```

I am trying to realise a OneToMany mapping between Car and Garage, and in general there arent occurring any errors. But the final result is not what i have exptected.

That is the result:
[image]

But i expect something like: 
[image]

(The number 1 on the picture is the ID of the garage, that has been inserted in the table Garage. Thats the exact garage, where i have added the cars in the MainTest)

I appreciate any kind of help! Spend hours on this but i cant see why i am getting null on that column.

Thanks.

Comment: This is being asked every other day. The owning side of the association is Car.carGarage. You need to set this side too, not just the inverse side: `oneCar.setCarGarage(garage)`.

Comment: Its working. Didnt know that, thank you.